# How to access a value outside the Model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

Actually i have two models , Products & Category , and category id act as a foreign key in Products , and I want to access all categories in product Index.html.erb by category id or any other way , i have the following idea although its a wrong approach.

```
<% if  product.category_id == 2 %>
    <td> furniture </td>

    <% elsif  product.category_id == 3 %>
    <td>Animals </td>
    <% else %>
    <td> No category </td>
    <% end %>
```

Her is my Product_controller.rb

```html
  
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end


  def show

  end


  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end


  def edit
  end


  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    @product.user = current_user
    @product.category = Category.first
    
    

  
  
  
  
  private
     actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

  
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:productname, :productprice, :productstatus,:image ,:category_id )
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declared the [associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) properly in your models – similar to this

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < AppicationRecord
  has_many :products
end
```

Then you should be able to just use `product.category` to load a product's category. Assuming a category has something like a `name` then you view could be simplified to something like this:

```
<td><%= product.category&.name || 'No category' %></td>
```

Comment: create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end                                                                                                                                                     Here is my table but when I apply   <td><%= product.category.name%></td>   an error occurs like  undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: That means you have at least one product in your database that doesn have an category. I will update my answer.